# Ignore eof character when reading csv to dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, eof

I have a csv file that I believe originated on Windows and has some line & file endings that I'm not used to. Between lines it has what show up in python as `'\r\n'`, and at the very end it has `'\r\n\x1a'` (when read in binary mode).

When I try to read with `pd.read_csv()`, it gives me an extra row with the first entry being `'\x1a'` and the rest as NaN.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: from StringIO import StringIO
In [3]: s = StringIO('a,b\r\n1,2\r\n3,4\r\n\x1a')
In [4]: df = pd.read_csv(s)
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   a   b
0  1   2
1  3   4
2   NaN
```

Is this file ending common enough that there's a built in option to ignore it in pandas? If not, any suggestions for not reading the EOF character into the dataframe or is the best way to manually test for it and drop the row after reading?

**Edit**:

My tentative solution is to apply this function after reading:

```
def strip_eof(df):
    "Drop last row if it begins with '\x1a' ends with NaN's"
    lastrow = df.iloc[-1]
    if lastrow[0] == '\x1a' and lastrow[1:].isnull().all():
        return df.drop([lastrow.name], axis=0)
    return df
```

Comment: looks like the csv parser gets everything except the last line. does just dropping the last line get you what you want? `skip_footer = 1`?

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it requires the python (not C) parsing engine, so for the specific file I'm reading it takes almost 10 times longer (1s vs 9s). It'd also be nice to only ignore the EOF, in case the format ever changes so that I don't lose the last line.

Comment: if this is consistent, you could modify your script to check for NAN on the last line and then remove it: `df[ : len(df)-1 ]` In the API docs i only see the ability to change the lineterminator which won't fix your problem.

Comment: Yeah I'll probably do something like that for now. Updated w/ current solution.

Comment: `df.tail(1)` will return the last row

Comment: Ha, I had this issue very recently... I just dropped the last line after reading (not very satisfactory), perhaps worth opening a github issue!

Comment: @AndyHayden Opened [7340](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7340).